# OpenCL won't work for cycles, Mac

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, osx, opencl

I just started usuing cycles render on a Mac, and Was told GPU rendering is much faster. The only problem is that the GPU rendering never happens it just makes a light grey and dark grey checker board, it isn't running out of space as it it usuing 60 MB and I have 1024. Can anyone help! Thanks.